# Python: Read the input file of delimited strings into a nested dictionary and loop through it

Tags: python, python-2.7

My input file would look like this:

```
1111;A:aaaa,B:aaaa,F:aaaa  
2222;A:aaaa,B:aaaa,E:aaaa  
3333;C:aaaa,D:aaaa,E:aaaa,F:aaaa  
4444;D:aaaa  
5555;C:bbbb  
2222;A:bbbb,B:bbbb  
2222;A:cccc,B:cccc  
1111;C:cccc,D:cccc,E:cccc,F:cccc  
2222;A:dddd,B:dddd  
1111;A:eeee,B:eeee  
1111;A:ffff,B:ffff  
2222;C:ffff,E:ffff,F:ffff  
1111;A:gggg,B:gggg,C:gggg  
3333;C:gggg,E:gggg,F:gggg  
5555;A:hhhh,B:hhhh
```

I would like to get something like in java would be nested maps with the list of strings in the inner map structure.

```
Map<'String, Map<'String, List{String}>>
```

something like this:

```
<1111:
      <'A':{'aaaa','eeee','ffff','gggg'}>
      <'B':{'aaaa','eeee','ffff','gggg'}>
      <'C':{'cccc','gggg'}>
      <'D':{'cccc'}>
      <'E':{'cccc'}>
      <'F':{'aaaa','cccc'}>
>
```

Comment: If you would like to do so, just do it. What is the question you have for this Q&A site?

Answer (score 2):

The Python equivalent of a Java `Map` is a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), and parsing such a simple input can be easily done with [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

The simplest way I can think of is:

```py
nested_dict = dict()

for line in file:
    key, val = line.split(';')
    if key not in nested_dict:
        nested_dict[key] = dict()
    for part in val.split(','):
        key2, val2 = part.split(':')
        if key2 not in nested_dict[key]:
            nested_dict[key][key2] = []
        nested_dict[key][key2].append(val2)
```

You could omit the `if` statements using a `defaultdict` to make it a bit nicer.

```
from collections import defaultdict
nested_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for line in file:
    key, val = line.split(';')
    for part in val.split(','):
        key2, val2 = part.split(':')
        nested_dict[key][key2].append(val2)
```

A remark: in these example even numeric keys are stored as strings. It might be desirable, but if not, you can simply convert them to integers using `int` when assigning the dict value.

#### Update

To iterate over the "leafs" of yous nested dictionary, you can use the `values` method of `dict`s, which returns an iterator over the dictionary values:

```py
for dct in nested_dict.values():
    for val in dct.values():
        do_something(val)
```

In python 2.7 and below using the `itervalues` method is recommended over `values`, as it returns an iterator instead of a list.

Also, you can write a simple generator that loops over the values.

```py
def leafgen(nested_dict):
    for dct in nested_dict.values():
        for val in dct.values():
            yield val
```

Then you can do

```py
for val in leafgen(nested_dict):
    do_something(val)
```

And you get some built-in functions for free, for example you can do

```
['aaaa'] in leafgen(nested_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted for creating a dictionary.

Comment: Now, how would I loop throuh it to do something for each val2?

Comment: Dicts provide a `values` method which returns an iterator with their values so you could do something like:
`for dct in nested_dict.values(): for val in dct.values(): do_something(val)` (I will update the answer with a properly indented version in a minute)